How to resolve Twilio Error 32011: "Error Communicating with Your SIP Communications Infrastructure"?
Issue with Incoming Calls on Twilio SIP Trunk - Error 32011
Hello everyone,
I'm experiencing an issue with incoming calls on my Twilio SIP trunk setup. Here are the details of the scenario:

The infrastructure includes a Grandstream PBX located behind a NATed IP.

Outgoing calls from my infrastructure are working perfectly.

However, incoming calls are failing, and I’m receiving the Twilio error code 32011.

The setup includes four peer trunks for the Virginia region, covering the IP range 54.172.60.0/30. Additionally, I have a registered SIP trunk configured for outgoing calls.

This setup had been working without issues until, suddenly, from one day to the next, incoming calls stopped working without any changes made to my infrastructure.


Does anyone have any insights into what might be causing this problem or how I can troubleshoot it effectively?
Thank you for your help!
